# Disable button tooltip when displaying modal

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, quasar-framework

I have a button that has a tooltip (for hover-over description purpose) that when clicked, displays a modal dialog.
My problem is that after the modal is closed, the tooltip is then displayed.

How can I cancel the tooltip if the button is clicked?

Edit: What actually seems to be happening is that after the modal is closed, the button that triggered the open, is focused again, which then triggers the tooltip to open. Perhaps there is a way, on close of a modal, dialog, etc, to not focus the element that triggered the open event.

Button

```
<q-btn @click="showTagManagementModel = true">
     <q-tooltip :delay="500">Edit display mode</q-tooltip>
</q-btn>
```

Modal

```
<q-modal v-model="showTagManagementModel">
      <q-btn @click="showTagManagementModel = false" label="Close" />
</q-modal>
```

Answer (score 0):

Quasar Modal component offers a "no-refocus" vue property.

> Do not refocus (on modal close) the element that had focus before
>   opening (by default it tries to refocus)

By setting this property on the q-modal, the button triggering the open will not refocus and then trigger the tooltip to show.